# Importing Excel files to MySQL

Tags: mysql, excel, import

I need to import an Excel file to MySQL but I can't find an appropriate way to do it. It has like 20 columns and 80k rows. Could someone help me please? I'm trying to build a portfolio project on it... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Save the excel file as CSV and then import it into mysql.

Example:
[https://phoenixnap.com/kb/import-csv-file-into-mysql#:~:text=1%20Import%20CSV%20File%20Using%20Command%20Line.%202,4%20Step%203%3A%20Import%20CSV%20into%20MySQL%20Table](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/import-csv-file-into-mysql#:%7E:text=1%20Import%20CSV%20File%20Using%20Command%20Line.%202,4%20Step%203%3A%20Import%20CSV%20into%20MySQL%20Table).